# Not adding customHeaders on some routes?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, http-headers, web-config

A standard way to add the `X-Frame-Options` header is to use the web.config file and add a `customHeaders` element.

```
<system.webServer>
  <!-- ... -->

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  <!-- ... -->
</system.webServer>
```

If I have a page that I *want* to be able to be iframed, is there a way to write this config to ignore the path or can I only do this in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the X-Frame-Options header within the global.asax file for ASP.NET application.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could do it by altering the web.config (I have a number of apps to change) but seems this is the only way.

Comment: Did you fail to add X-Frame-Options through <customHeaders>?

Comment: My issue is I want to exclude it from some paths/routes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, you said above you hope you can  do it by altering the web.config,  but now you say you want to exclude it from some paths/route. what is paths/route?